# Could not locate Gemfile: gemfile not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, bundle, gemfile, locate

I just installed rails and I got the following message after creating "rails new mySite" and running "bundle install". I know gemfile is in the same folder and I checked it by typing "gem -v". I don't know what went wrong. Below is what I see when I run "bundle env". 
[bundle env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7HbH.png)

Comment: Check a file named `gemfile.lock` in your project. It should be there. If not, then this error is telling you that. I don't know how it cannot be there.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please be so nice and help us to help you. Take a minute or two and transcribe the contents of your screenshot and provide it as text. Rationale can be found at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question.

Comment: are you in correct directory? After you create `rails new mySite` go to that directory and then `bundle install`

Comment: Yes, I am in the correct directory. I did "rails new mySite" - "cd mySite" - "bundle install" but it keeps saying that gemfile is not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
rails new mySite
cd mySite
bundle install
```

You need to be inside the project home directory to use `bundle` command.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, I am in the project home directory but it still doesn’t work.

Answer (score 1):

Before you run `bundle install` make sure the Gemfile has the proper name.

1 `Gemfile` instead of `gemfile`, the file is capitalized and has no file-type.

2 Make sure to `cd` the terminal location should be in the same location of you `Gemfile`

Answer (score 0):

**Create a Gemfile and paste this code to the Gemfile.**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.7'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', '< 1.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: Thank you but it doens't seem to work.. Now it says "Could not find gem 'uglifier (>= 1.3.0) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile." Sorry, I am new...

Comment: When you import this GEmfile, you must run in the console: bundle install